# Minimizing the surface area of a rectangular prism

Tags: geometry

Why is it that a rectangular prism with known sum of all side lengths that is a cube has the greatest surface area while a square based prism with known volume is a cube that has the least surface area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the side-lengths of a rectangular prism be $a, b, c$.  Suppose that $a+b+c = P$.  Now we have $$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2 \geq 0.$$ Expanding yields $$2a^2+2b^2+2c^2-2ab-2bc-2ca \geq 0 \Rightarrow a^2+b^2+c^2 \geq ab+bc+ca.$$ Now if we add $2ab+2bc+2ca$ to both sides we get $$a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ca \geq 3ab+3bc+3ca,$$ which gives you $$P^2 = (a+b+c)^2 \geq 3(ab+bc+ca) \Rightarrow 2(ab+bc+ca) \leq \dfrac{2P^2}{3}.$$

The inequality is equality when $a=b=c$, or when the prism is a cube.  This is when the surface area, $2(ab+bc+ca)$ is minimized.

---

If the volume $V=abc$ is fixed, then by the [Arithmetic Mean Geometric Mean Inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean_Inequality): $$\dfrac{ab+bc+ca}{3} \geq \sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2} = \sqrt[3]{V^2},$$ so $$2(ab+bc+ca) \geq 6\sqrt[3]{V^2}.$$  The equality case of AM-GM is $ab=bc=ca$ which implies $a=b=c$, so again a cube minimizes the surface area.

Comment: you say that if sum of side lengths is known, then minimum possible surface area is when the rectangular prism is a cube, right? But for example, when the sum of all the edges of a rectangular prism is 72, the maximum surface area is when it is a cube, right? Please explain this as i am only in grade 8 and only somewhat understood the 1st part of your answer.

Comment: There are twelve edges of a rectangular prism, so if the sum of all of them is 72 and it is a cube then each edge should be 6.  That makes the surface area 54.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Wouldn't a cube with s = 6 have a surface area of 216? What I am asking is that you say that a rectangular prism with a known sum of sides has the least surface area when it is a cube. But, a cube with 6 has the maximum possible surface area. Why is it that a rectangular prism with known sum of sides has largest possible surface area when it is cube, but a square based pyramid with known volume has last possible surface area when it is a cube?

Comment: Sorry, it is indeed 216, I'm not sure what I was thinking when I wrote 54.  To answer your question of why one is an upper bound and one is a lower bound, that is simply the nature of the quantities $(a+b+c)^2$, $ab+bc+ca$, and $abc$ when compared with each other; we always have $(a+b+c)^2 \geq 3(ab+bc+ca) \geq 9\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}$.

Comment: Ooohhhhh! Thanks a lot, I understand now, it's because of the inequality. Thanks!